# GCE - Can not create an instance image from the startup script

Tags: rsync, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a GCE instance image from its startup script (just after some setup instructions). I use a command line looking like :

```
gcimagebundle -d "/dev/sda" -o "/tmp/" --log_file=/var/log/image_generation.log "--output_file_name=/tmp/myimage.tar.gz"
```

After few seconds the **gcimagebundle** exits and I get the following error message (from the /var/log/image_generation.log file) :

```
INFO:root:found platform Centos
INFO:root:File System: ext4
INFO:root:Disk Size: 10737418240 bytes
INFO:root:Resolved /dev/sda to /dev/sda
INFO:root:exclude list: (/etc/ssh/.host_key_regenerated, 0:0:0) (/dev, 0:1:0) (/proc, 0:1:0) (/run, 0:1:1) (/selinux, 0:0:0) (/tmp, 0:1:0) (/sys, 0:1:0) (/var/lib/google/per-   instance, 0:1:0) (/var/lock, 0:1:1) (/var/log, 0:1:1) (/var/run, 0:1:1)
INFO:root:ignoring mounts /proc /sys /dev/pts /dev/shm /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
WARNING:root:overwrite list = 
INFO:root:Initializing disk file
INFO:root:Making filesystem
INFO:root:Copying contents
WARNING:root:Error while running ['rsync', '--times', '--perms', '--owner', '--group', '--links', '--devices', '--acls', '--sparse', '--hard-links', '--recursive', '--xattrs', '--exclude-from=/tmp/tmpXtECHY/tmp6Y_7Dr', '/', '/tmp/tmpXtECHY/tmpencYI_'] return_code = 11
stdout=
stderr=rsync: failed to open exclude file /tmp/tmpXtECHY/tmp6Y_7Dr: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at exclude.c(1062) [client=3.0.6]
```

I tried to execute the same startup script on a fresh instance after a manual `sudo su` and all works.

I execute a `whoami` from the startup script and the result is `root`.

Comment: can you post the source of your startup script?

Comment: No sorry it's for business... But I am just making some `curl`, `wget` and `chmod` (outside of the tmp directory). I have just opened a ticket on the GCE support.

Comment: I have launched an instance with the following trimmed down startup script :`#!/bin/bash

gcimagebundle -d "/dev/sda" -o "/tmp/" --log_file=/var/log/image_generation.log --output_file_name="/tmp/myimage.tar.gz"`

I got the same error...

Comment: @BenoîtS. have you solved your issue? If not, have you tried running `gcimagebundle` command on its own in a startup script to see if it works without any other commands, and then incrementally narrowing down what command is causing the issue?

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, I had tried just with the `gcimagebundle` command but it still does not work.